# How do I set Dev-C++ compiler to work with a C library?

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++, libjpeg

I have downloaded and setup the libjpeg package for Dev C++. I have ensured it is the most recent version. 
Then I have added the respective libraries in Dev C++:

Tools > Compiler > Directories
I also have the compiler set to TDM-GCC 4.8.1 64-bit Release

What I have added:
Bin:
Dev-Cpp\bin

Libraries:
Dev-Cpp\lib

C Includes:
Dev-Cpp\include

C++ Includes:
Dev-Cpp\include

I have also add a link in the project parameters
Linker:
Dev-Cpp/lib/libjpeg.a

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <cstdio> 

extern "C" {

  #include <jpeglib.h>  
  #include <jerror.h>
}

int main(void)
{ 
  struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo; 
  struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr; 
  cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(& jerr); 
  jpeg_create_decompress(& cinfo); 
  return 0; 
}
```

I am getting the errors:

```
D:\FP\main.o    In function `main':
14      D:\FP\main.cpp  undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
15      D:\FP\main.cpp  undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress'
...
```

I have looked at this [post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=9322) which seems relevant but I don't know how to apply it to C++.
In that forum I've linked to, the problem was somehow solved when a commenter told the OP to specify which compiler was used for the library. I.e. GCC for C and G++ for C++. I am getting the same errors as he did, so I think it is related, but I'm not sure how to reconfigure it.

I've looked at the post:

[What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fixquestion)

But this does not answer my question as this is a general answer for undefined references.

Comment: _"as this is a general answer for undefined references"_ Yes, read it

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've just finished reading it. It's very informative, but it doesn't seem to have the answer I'm looking for. There is a reference to C libs in C++ and I've already done what was suggested. One thing did seem relevant however, and it was "In gcc you'd add the files to the command line"--regarding the linking. This is similar to what I have mentioned in my question but it does not elaborate how to do it. Which is what I want to know.

Comment: @Klik how to add linker flags or objects to link should be mentioned in the documentation of your IDE.

Comment: @PeterT That sounds like some great terms that I can google. Since I have been looking for the better part of 5 hours, could you just confirm for me that it is indeed a linking problem? Even though I have already added a linking parameter in the project options.

Comment: @Klik yes, it found the header and all the symbols, it marked `jpeg_std_error` and `jpeg_CreateDecompress` as symbols that are defined "somewhere else". During the linking stage it didn't find them anywhere though. As the answers to the linked question should make clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have set up your IDE to find libraries in the correct place, but you have not set up your project to actually link with *libjpeg*. In your project settings, you will find a place to do so.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to mention my links. I have tried linking with: Dev-Cpp/lib/libjpeg.a and Dev-Cpp/lib/libjpeg.dll.a. I've tried doing each one separately and then both together.

Comment: @Klik: Remotely I'm not going to be able to see what you did wrong. You could show a bunch of screenshots of your project settings, but this is getting way out of the scope of a Q&A repository. Have you tried asking in a chatroom or on a forum?

Comment: For the past three hours I have been trying to set up libjpeg. I thought this is a forum that would be able to answer my question? Would you have a suggestion for me?

Comment: The question this is linking to does not answer my question. My question is with regards to implementing libjpeg in Dev C++. It is especially tricky since libjpeg is a C library and I'm using C++ code. In the other forum I've linked to, the problem was somehow solved when a commenter told the OP to specify which compiler was used for the library.

Comment: _"It is especially tricky since libjpeg is a C library and I'm using C++ code."_ That does not make it tricky whatsoever.

Comment: @Klik: This is not a "forum".